# ReactJS two-way binding with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm writting ReactJS application with [Typescript](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts) and I don't know how to specify two-way bindings:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html

There is no valueLink available on React.Component class. The component could implement LinkedStateMixin interface but I don't know what should be the content of linkState method and how to connect everything together.

Can anyone provide me some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> valueLink available on React.Component class

This is because React *classes* do not support *mixins*.

To use the `LinkedStateMixin` mixin you need to use `createClass` and that is complete *unrecommeded* for code safety in TypeScript / ES6 classes land.

## More

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html

[image]